# How can I create a centered responsive menu

Tags: css

I have some troubles creating a menu that has 4 items and should be be centered beside each other with a gap between them, and if on mobile device be stacked on each other. The menu should look like the image here...

[image]

Can someone please show how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do so, just with a ul list and few lines of CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

    <head>
        <style>

            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .menu {
                list-style-type: none;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .menu li {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                margin: 8px 8px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.336)
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            
                .menu li {
                    display: block;
                }

            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Menu1</li>
            <li>Menu2</li>
            <li>Menu3</li>
            <li>Menu4</li>
        </ul>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is to build the container with the menu buttons. Ofcourse you need to style these yourselves:

```
<div class="navContainer">
  <input type="button" value="Menu1"/>
  <input type="button" value="Menu2"/>
  <input type="button" value="Menu3"/>
  <input type="button" value="Menu4"/>
</div>
```

And this is to justify it's position and margin. It also includes a media query which will make the inputs stack below 500px

```
<style>
  .navContainer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .navContainer input {
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width:500px){
    .navContainer {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Possible, but I would do margin: 0 15px; instead of just left margin, to keep it clean